# Web Config Rule Match

Tags: .net, web-config

I have two rules on my web config that is in conflict with some url.

This first rule have to redirect to the website:

```
<rule name="Pop Up Cadastro">
    <match url="^cadastro" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="site/site.php?url={R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

This second rule will redirect to the hotsite if no match is found:

```
<rule name="HotSite">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="HotSite/Default.aspx?url={R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

My url structure looks like this:

```
//WebSite URL | First Rule
www.example.com/cadastro

//HotSite URL | Second Rule
www.example.com/cadastro-teste-e-com
```

- This works for the hole website but when i have this url (cadastro-teste-e-com) i'm redirected to the website instead of the hotsite.
- The orders of the rules are the same as i posted here.

So, my question is, is there any way to limit the first rule to only the word **cadastro** ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first rule you have regex that match everything that starts with cadastro, if you want to match only cadastro you need to add $ at the end of regex.

```
<rule name="Pop Up Cadastro">
    <match url="^cadastro$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="site/site.php?url={R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: So the $ means "only what i have on the match url tag" ?

Comment: $ matches end of line/string. That means ^cadastro$ will match [start of string]cadastro[end of string] and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks buddy, that was really useful.
By the way, is there any way i can learn more about these rules ?
Thanks

Comment: Tks buddy, i will take a look !